# Where are constraints on generic parameters in documentation?

Tags: c#

Some generic classes have constraints on its generic parameters. For example, keys in dictionaries should implement some interfaces (to be comparable...) with `where ...` clause. Where I can find those constraints in the documentation in https://learn.microsoft.com?

For example, I see information about all interfaces of dictionaries, but no information about constraints of `TKey` type parameter.

Comment: Are you talking specifically about the `TKey` generic from the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface or do you talk about generic parameters in general in all the classes/interfaces? What exactly are you asking or looking for?

Comment: Both. My goal is to understand where to look for such information. Without VS help. For example, in Haskell I see it in Hackage documentation as constrains (like `Eq a`, which means `a` instantiates `Eq` class). I know that such info exists in .NET, but I can not find it in Microsoft site.

Comment: You can check the documentation of that class that uses generics when you want to know if there are any boundaries for that generic parameter. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary's `TKey` parameter has no constraints, Zohar has talked much about this.

Most generic parameters in .Net Framework has no constraints, if a generic parameter has any constraints then you can see `where` clause in its defination, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemoryaccessor.read?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think keys should implement an interface to be comparable?

The documentation of [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) does not say that anywhere.
In fact, it clearly states what happens when TKey does not implement the IEquatable interface (emphasis mine):

> Dictionary requires an equality implementation to determine whether keys are equal.
>   You **can** specify an implementation of the `IEqualityComparer<T>` generic interface by using a constructor that accepts a comparer parameter;
>   **if you do not specify an implementation, the default generic equality comparer `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` is used.**
>   If type `TKey` implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` generic interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation.

The fact is, that an instance of any type in the .Net framework can be compared to other instances of the same type, whether it does or does not implement the `System.IEquatable<T>` or `System.IComparable<T>` interfaces. It's just being compared by the [default comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.equalitycomparer-1.default?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_EqualityComparer_1_Default).